# Angular.js return undfined in same code different pages

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

The application is running on sails.js as backend and Angular as frontend,
It is CRUD application and there two pages, one is the main Dashboard and other is Search.html that have advanced search functionalities.

here the thing two pages, use identical ng-repeat that inject same html page which contain same function with same controller that use same service.

Here how it goes, I click on the delete button which fire showCancelQuoteModal(quote), then I click on the confirmation and fire ng-click=cancelQoute which pass decisionFrom without any problems.

now in cancelQouteModalCtrl both qoute and decisionForm are passed without a problem to qouteLogService, where qoute still there and qoutelog contain cancellationReason.

and qoute.post should return createdQouteLog but it doesn't in search .html and does in Dashboard.html

when I started tracking and watching the var, everything disappear when the code get in Angular.js and the following stack

$scope.apply() / $scope.digest() /$scope.eval() /processQueue()

here the table of Dashboard.html and search.html

```
       <table class="table table-striped table-responsive" ui-jq="footable" data-filter="#filter19"
                   data-page-size="{{pageControl.pageSize}}">
              <thead>
              <tr>
                <th data-type="date">Last Update</th>
                <th>Client</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Dealer</th>
                <th>Assigned To</th>
                <th data-type="numeric">Status</th>
                <th>Progress</th>
                <th>Actions</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>

              <tr ng-repeat="quote in allQuotes | orderBy: '-updatedAt' track by quote.id"
                  ng-init="latestQuoteLog=findLatestQuoteLog(quote.quoteLogs)">
                <td class="text-center" data-value="{{latestQuoteLog.createdAt}}">
                  {{latestQuoteLog.createdAt | date : 'dd-MMM-yy hh:mm a'}}
                </td>

                <td>{{quote.client.name}}</td>

                <td>{{quote.client.phone | tel}}</td>

                <td ng-if="quote.dealershipCompany">{{quote.dealershipCompany.name}}</td>
                <td ng-if="!quote.dealershipCompany">Online</td>

                <td>{{username(latestQuoteLog.assignedTo)}}</td>

                <td data-value="{{latestQuoteLog.status}}">
                    <span class="label bg-{{quoteStatusIdToStatusName[latestQuoteLog.status]}}">
                      {{quoteStatusPrettyNames[latestQuoteLog.status]}}
                    </span>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class="progress-xs progress ng-isolate-scope w-sm m-t-sm" type="info">
                    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-primary" role="progressbar"
                         aria-valuenow="{{quoteStatusProgress[latestQuoteLog.status]}}" aria-valuemin="0"
                         aria-valuemax="100" ng-
                         style="width: {{quoteStatusProgress[latestQuoteLog.status]}}%;"></div>
                  </div>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <div class=" btn-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon btn-default"
                            ng-if="latestQuoteLog.status != quoteStatus.quoteCancelled"
                            ng-click="showCancelQuoteModal(quote)">
                      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" tooltip="Cancel Quote"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon  btn-default" ng-click="editQuote(quote)">
                      <i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-edit" tooltip="Edit Quote"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon  btn-default" ng-click="viewQuote(quote)">
                      <i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-eye-open" tooltip="View Quote"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon  btn-default"
                            ng-click="showModal(quote, roles.broker, 'AT', latestQuoteLog)"
                            ng-if="canAssign(latestQuoteLog, roles.broker)">
                      <i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-arrow-right" tooltip="Assign To Broker"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon  btn-default"
                            ng-click="showModal(quote, roles.processor, 'AT', latestQuoteLog)"
                            ng-if="canAssign(latestQuoteLog, roles.processor)">
                      <i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-arrow-right" tooltip="Assign To Processor"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon  btn-default" ng-click="showModal(quote, roles.broker, 'CA')"
                            ng-if="canChangeAssignee(latestQuoteLog, roles.broker)">
                      <i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-transfer" tooltip="Change Assignee"></i>
                    </button>
                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-icon  btn-default"
                            ng-click="showModal(quote, roles.processor, 'CA')"
                            ng-if="canChangeAssignee(latestQuoteLog, roles.processor)">
                      <i class="glyphicon  glyphicon-transfer" tooltip="Change Assignee"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </td>
              </tr>

              </tbody>
              <tfoot class="hide-if-no-paging">
              <tr>
                <td colspan="9" class="text-center">
                  <ul class="pagination"></ul>
                </td>
              </tr>
              </tfoot>
            </table>
```

here cancelModal

```
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="cancelQuoteModal.html">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <form name="decisionForm" class="form-horizontal wrapper input-set">
          <div class="col-md-10">
            <label>
              <h4 class="font-thin">Why it is not sold ?</h4>
            </label>
            <select class="form-control" ng-model="reasonForRejection" name="reasonForRejection" required>
              <option ng-repeat="reason in rejectionReasons" value="{{reason}}">
                {{reason}}
              </option>
            </select>
            <small
              ng-show="(decisionForm.reasonForRejection.$invalid && !decisionForm.reasonForRejection.$pristine) || showErrors"
              class="b-light  m-t-n-sm m-b font-thin text-danger m-r">Reason is required.
            </small>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success" ng-click="cancelQuote(decisionForm)">Confirm Quote Cancellation</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancelBox()">Close!</button>
      </div>

    </script>
```

Here CancelModalController

```
 .controller('cancelQuoteModalCtrl', ['$scope', '$modalInstance', 'quoteLogService', 'rejectionReasons', 'quote', function ($scope, $modalInstance, quoteLogService, rejectionReasons, quote) {
    $scope.rejectionReasons = rejectionReasons;
    $scope.reasonForRejection;

    $scope.cancelQuote = function (decisionForm) {
      if (decisionForm.$invalid) {
        $scope.showErrors = true;
      } else {
        quoteLogService.create(quote, {
          'status': 'quoteCancelled',
          'cancellationReason': $scope.reasonForRejection
        }, function (createdQuoteLog) {
          $modalInstance.close('Quote cancelled successfully!');

        }, function (err) {
          $modalInstance.dismiss('Error creating new quoteLog');
          console.log('Error creating new quoteLog', err);
        });
      }
    };

    $scope.cancelBox = function () {
      $modalInstance.close();
    };

  }]);
```

And here QouteLogService.js

```
QuoteLogModule
.factory('quoteLogService', ['$localStorage', '$state', 'LoggedInRestangular', function($localStorage, $state, LoggedInRestangular) {
    return {
        create: function(quote, quotelog, success, error) {
            quote.post('quotelog', quotelog).then(function(createdQuoteLog) {
                success(createdQuoteLog);
            }, function(err) {
                error(err);
            });
        },
```